# AutoResize ContainerView's Width According To Dynamic UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, autoresize, uicontainerview

I have 3 labels with bullet points that are placed horizontally. I want to give bullet points custom design so I thought I should use them as UIImage. Let me illustrate it:

```
o PHP  o Swift  o Java
```

There will be fixed distance between each label and it's assigned bullet point. Labels will also have a fixed distance with the next label's bullet point (eg PHP - Swift's bullet point).

In the end, I want to center it horizontally to the view.

Above scenario would work if I have static texts for label. However, I want to use dynamic texts.

---

The solution I thought was creating 3 container views. So I would have:

```
View

   ContainerView1   ContainerView2   ContainerView3
   |------------|  |--------------| |--------------|
   |   o PHP    |  |    o Swift   | |    o C       |
   |------------|  |--------------| |--------------|
```

But it won't look consistent for dynamic/changing text sizes. I will use sizeToFit to make the text fit but the container views have created new separate ViewController, so I am not sure if I can make container views' width to auto-adjust itself to *'Bullet Point + dynamic Label's width'*.

```
Parent ContainerView (or UIView?)
|-----------------------------|
|     CV1      CV2     CV3    |
|   |-----| |-------| |---|   |
|   |o PHP| |o Swift| |o C|   |
|   |-----| |-------| |---|   |
|-----------------------------|
```

This scenario would only work if I can auto-manipulate the width of 'container view' regarding on the *Bullet Point + Label's width*. Thus, I can make fixed margin for each container and center them horizontally (maybe by using a parent container).

What is the way to achieve that? Is there a way to do it on Storyboard or programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent container view will auto adjust the width to fit the content inside if all your `CV` views have a width than can be determined by autolayout (you said you'll use sizetofit for this). Then they must have fixed vertical spaceing between the and the first and last also must have margins to the parent container (leading and trailing). The parent container must not have a constrained width (fixed width constraint for instance) because it must resize according to the content inside and if it does this results in a constraint conflict and it won't work.
If you do not use autolayout for the parent view container or you have a width constraint you could get the size of the container using

```
let size = parentViewContainer. systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
```

and set it to either the frame or the width constraint.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3h26bFy0wEURU16ZEsxVGJ3VGs) is a sample project demonstrating this.

Comment: I didn't really get how the CV1 will understand the UILabel's sizeToFit change and update its own width to the new width (bullet + label width). At this point, I understand that the CV1 - CV2 and CV2 - CV3 will have fixed margins. But now how will the ParentCV will adjust its width according to the CVs and the CVs not get adjusted (if I use leading & trailing from CVs to ParentCV). After that centering ParentContainer to SuperView horizontally is pretty straight forward. Can you please give me more details?

Comment: Inside `CV`s you must apply the same method as in the parent Because you essentially want the same thing. So you should set the leading margin for the bullet image, vertical spacing between the bullet image and the label and trailing margin for the label. And this should be it, autolayout will set the width of the `CV` based on the content inside.

Comment: Can you please create a sample project if it is not too much to ask? I am really confused and very excited for learning this. What ever I try, something is failing :S

Comment: Wow. That's great how you achieved it.. Can I please ask one more thing? Can you please add in your answer the steps you took to achieve this? I'd be so very grateful for that! Because I'm curious about which constraints you setup, in which order. Your constraints seem so clean.

Comment: Well the order doesn't really matter. I think I already explained how this is achieved. Basically you must make sure that the content inside a container has a fixed size or can be computed based on its subviews (it does not have an ambiguous size in terms of autolayout) and it also has margins to the superview so that the superview can also compute its size based on the content.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Maybe I should try harder!

Comment: No problem. Don't beat yourself too hard. It takes some time to get a hang of autolayout and think in terms on constraints. Good luck!

Comment: After hours of work, I understood the logic. Instead of 'Trailing' left container and 'Leading' right container to the parent's sides, first I give fixed margins to the middle one too (for left & right container). After that, the trick was centering the middle container horizontally. Huge thanks @Jelly